# php Mail() function doesn't work

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I'm working on a php script which has to send emails. But my mail() function doesn't work. I know that I have to configure somehow php.ini and may be something else but I don't know what exactly and how. I installed sendmail, by the way.
Any ideas?  Thanks a lot.
this is my code.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

$to  = 'name@gmail.com';

$subject = 'subject';

$message = 'text';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: user <user@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: server <server@example.com>' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

in php.ini i put `sendmail_path ="/usr/sbin/sendmail"`

ps. i Use Ubuntu

guys, in the mail.log file i got

```
Apr 29 16:12:05 IT02 sendmail[7660]: My unqualified host name (IT02) unknown; sleeping    for retry 
Apr 29 16:13:05 IT02 sendmail[7660]: unable to qualify my own domain name (IT02) -- using short name 
Apr 29 16:13:05 IT02 sendmail[7660]: p3TED551007660: from=www-data, size=210, class=0, nrcpts=0, msgid=<201104291413.p3TED551007660@IT02>, bodytype=8BITMIME, relay=www-data@localhost
```

Does anybody know what it means?

Comment: show some code or atleast say what error u get. And which OS are you using Linux or Windows???

Comment: @Kuen, for information your question is not so clear. No, one can understand this and answer you. Improve the Description given.

Comment: it could be supposed that the server is linux and the directive to configure is the one relative to sendmail

Comment: sorry, guys, my bad. I use ubuntu,

Comment: @Kuen, edit your original post with that code and information.  It isn't readable as a comment.

Comment: How come you assume immediately that it's php's function that doesn't work and not the mail program? Do you even have sendmail and if yes, is it configured properly? Did you test your sendmail program without the use of php?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first step would be to figure out where sendmail is installed.  Once you know that path, go into your php.ini.  You are looking for the `sendmail_path` setting.  Set it appropriately.

If the path is set correctly, the result from a proper call to `mail()` should return `true`.  (Note that the return value only lets you know if the message was passed on to sendmail [or SMTP in the case of Windows].  It does not guarantee that the e-mail went out, or that sendmail is configured correctly.)  If it is returning `true` and you still aren't getting e-mail, then check your sendmail configuration.

Comment: sendmail is installed. in the mail.log i got: Apr 29 16:12:05 IT02 sendmail[7660]: My unqualified host name (IT02) unknown; sleeping for retry
Apr 29 16:13:05 IT02 sendmail[7660]: unable to qualify my own domain name (IT02) -- using short name
Apr 29 16:13:05 IT02 sendmail[7660]: p3TED551007660: from=www-data, size=210, class=0, nrcpts=0, msgid=<201104291413.p3TED551007660@IT02>, bodytype=8BITMIME, relay=www-data@localhost

Comment: So, your problem has nothing to do with PHP at all.  Not to mention, this is an extremely common issue.  http://www.fedoraforum.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-85365.html